# How To Convert hibernate xml many-to-many mapping having formula into annotation?

Tags: hibernate

```
<set name="users"
table = "USER_RESTRICTION_ITEMS"
schema = "ABC"
lazy = true >
<key>
<column name = "USER_RESTRICTION_ID">
</key>
<many-to-many
class="com.xyz.com.data.User"
formula="TRIM(USER_ID)"
<many-to-many>
</set>
```

I have 3 tables USER,USER_RESTRICTION and USER_RESTRICTION_ITEMS
and i have 2 classes User and UserRestriction .

Pojo for UserRestriction is below having User class as a parameter I have to create @ManyToMany Relationship between them using formula like above xml code

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_RESTRICTION")
class UserRestriction {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "USER_RESTRICTION_ID")
  private Long id;

  private Set<User> users;

}
```

the third table USER_RESTRICTION_ITEMS contains column USER_ID,USER_RESTRICTION_ID

I have tried simple Many to many mapping but not able to use TRIM(USER_ID) in formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's currently no way to do this using annotations, and I think I can see why.

The problem is that for `@ManyToMany`, the `@JoinColumn` annotation is supposed to belong to `@JoinTable`, since you can have both `joinColumns` and `inverseJoinColumns`. (This is in compliance with the JPA spec.)

That doesn't leave us with a natural place to *put* a `@JoinFormula` annotation. At least, not without introducing our own ugly `@JoinTableWithFormula` annotation or something. And I can see why nobody ever wanted to add that.

But let me think about this a bit. It's annoying that Hibernate has useful functionality only accessible via XML.

Comment: A very rough POC solution to this is here: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/5976 but that would not be the final form of the solution.

Comment: Thanks @Gavin King. is there any alternative solution to do that ?

Comment: Well, sure, the my usual recommendation is to avoid `@ManyToMany`, and model the association table with an entity class. It just makes things easier.

Comment: Okay Got It @Gavin King. Thanks again. I have another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75176409/how-to-convert-hibernate-many-to-any-xml-mapping-into-annotations . do u have any idea about this?